# Python - Class references another class before assignment

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am working with sqlalchemy's ORM to create classes mapped to SQL tables. I am running into issues generating the relationships between these classes since they reference each other before the class is declared. When I run the code the interpreter complains `NameError: name 'Account' is not defined`

I've included a code sample below that demonstrates how I am declaring these classes.

```
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    address = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    state = Column(String)
    zip_code = Column(String)

    account = sa.orm.relationship('Account', order_by=Account.id, back_populates='location')
    entity = sa.orm.relationship('Entity', order_by=Entity.id, back_populates='location')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Location(name='{}', address='{}', city='{}', state='{}', zip_code='{}')>".\
                    format(self.name, self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zip_code)


class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    number = Column(String)
    institution = Column(String)
    # entity_id   = Column(Integer, sa.ForeignKey('entities.id'))

    entity = sa.orm.relationship('Entity', back_populates='accounts')
    location = sa.orm.relationship('Location', order_by=Location.id, back_populates='account')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Account(name='{}', account={}, institution={}, entity={})>".\
                format(self.name, self.number, self.institution, self.entity)


class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entities'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    accounts = sa.orm.relationship('Account', order_by=Account.id, back_populates='entity')
    location = sa.orm.relationship('Location', order_by=Location.id, back_populates='entity')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Entity(name='{}', location='{}')>".format(self.name, self.location)
```

What am I missing here? Is there a way to define all classes and then call them later as you can with functions? For example with functions, it's simple to call main at the bottom after all the functions are defined:

```
def main():
    foo()

def foo():

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define you orderings either as callables or as expression strings, as explained in the [relationship API documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#relationships-api):

```
class Location(Base):
    ...
    account = sa.orm.relationship('Account',
        order_by=lambda: Account.id, ...)
```

or

```
class Location(Base):
    ...
    account = sa.orm.relationship('Account',
        order_by='Account.id', ...)
```

The problem is that during evaluation of Location class' body the name Account does not yet exist in the global scope, and was not defined in the local scope of the class body. Passing in a function/lambda allows deferring the evaluation to "mapper initialization time":

> Some arguments accepted by `relationship()` optionally accept a callable function, which when called produces the desired value. The callable is invoked by the parent `Mapper` at “mapper initialization” time, which happens only when mappers are first used, and is assumed to be after all mappings have been constructed. This can be used to resolve order-of-declaration and other dependency issues, such as if `Child` is declared below `Parent` in the same file

Passing a string will also resolve the order-of-declaration issue, and provides another feature:

> These string arguments are converted into callables that evaluate the string as Python code, using the Declarative class-registry as a namespace. This allows the lookup of related classes to be automatic via their string name, and **removes the need to import related classes at all into the local module space**

Comment: Thanks! I realized after posting this question that the issue likely had something to do with the order_by parameter in the orm relationship, but I didn't realize there was another way to define these to avoid this problem.